# Possible to calculate predicted probabilities for each random effect level?

Tags: prediction, mixed-models, random-effects, glmmtmb

I've run a generalized linear mixed model with a binomial distribution with success of taking a seed as the response (Yes/No). Individual id is a random effect. Is it possible to not just calculate predicted probabilities based on the fixed effects but for each individual as well?

I want to be able to say what the predicted probability, with 95% CI, of being successful is for each individual.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **ggeffects** package. Predicted probabilities for different subjects should work in the same way as for linear models, and is [described in detail here](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_randomeffects.html#marginal-effects-for-each-level-of-random-effects-1).

However, currently you can't get confidence intervals for random effects when calculating predicted values for group levels / subjects... (any hints how to implement this are welcome!)

Example:

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(ggeffects)

data("cbpp")
set.seed(123)
cbpp$cont <- rnorm(nrow(cbpp))

# categorical predictor
m1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd), 
            data = cbpp, family = binomial)

me <- ggpredict(m1, terms = c("period", "herd [1,5,10,15]"), type = "re")
plot(me)
#> Loading required namespace: ggplot2
```

[image]

```r
# continuous predictor
m2 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ I(cont^2) + (1 | herd), 
            data = cbpp, family = binomial)

me <- ggpredict(m2, terms = c("cont", "herd [1,5,15]"), type = "re")
#> Model contains polynomial or cubic / quadratic terms. Consider using `terms="cont [all]"` to get smooth plots. See also package-vignette 'Marginal Effects at Specific Values'.
plot(me)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Daniel! Why can't you get confidence intervals for random effects when calculating predicted values for group levels / subjects?